# The adjective for leaving a position -- as in a job

Tags: adjectives

What is the adjective used for an employee (of a large company or agency) who is leaving a company? Not retiring... I am looking for the adjective that would apply to an employee as does "rising" senior applies to a student.

Is it "exiting" president/chair/CEO?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with "leaving"?  He is leaving his position as ____ . Going on to other things.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to distinguish the person who currently has the job from his (imminent) successor, I would recommend *outgoing*.

> "The outgoing CEO recommended Sarah to be his replacement."

Be warned, *outgoing* [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outgoing) "retiring or withdrawing from a place or position", but it also means "openly friendly and responsive:  *extroverted*", which is very different.

> "The outgoing CEO slapped every visitor on the back."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***departing***.  Oxford Dictionaries has this definition (Note especially #1.2)

> ***[depart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/depart)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Leave, especially in order to start a journey.
>      *‘they departed for Germany’*
>      *‘a contingent was departing from Cairo’*
>
>    1.1 depart from Deviate from (an accepted, prescribed, or usual course of action)
>        *‘he departed from the precedent set by many’*
>
>    1.2 North American with object Leave (one's job)
>        *‘he will soon depart his post as high commissioner to Britain’*

If you wanted an informal term for such a person, you could call them a ***[short-timer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/short-timer)***.